# C# FileHelpers Excluding Fields From Write

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am using Filehelpers to export a collection of a class to a csv file.

The class is used to store user info and has 5 fields, i want to export different fields in different circumstances.
so the collection will either be all new users where i only have values for say fields 1,2,3 or deleted users where only fields 1,4,5 have values.
I m declaring the fields as optional, however when i call write file all fields are included in the output.

Does anyone have any idea on teh best way to do this, im a bit stumped.

```
[FieldOptional()]
          [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
          public String JobTitle;

          [FieldOptional()]
          [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
          public String Department;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FieldOptional` attribute is used only when importing to signify that a field may be missing from the import file.

It is not clear from your question whether you need your field 4 and field 5 to appear empty in the case of a new user, e.g.,

```
Field1, Field2, Field3,,,
```

in which case, you can just set Field4 and Field5 to null.

Or perhaps you want them omitted completely,

```
Field1, Field2, Field3
```

in which case you can use an `AfterWriteEvent`. Something like

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Person>();
engine.AfterWriteRecord += engine_AfterWriteRecord;

static void engine_AfterWriteRecord(EngineBase engine, AfterWriteEventArgs<Person> e)
{
    // trim trailing empty separators
    e.RecordLine = e.RecordLine.TrimEnd(',');
}
```

As an alternative to attaching an event, you can have your FileHelpers class implement the`INotifyWrite<T>` interface

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
class User : INotifyWrite<User>
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
    public string Field3;
    public string Field4;
    public string Field5;

    public void BeforeWrite(BeforeWriteEventArgs<User> e)
    {
    }

    public void AfterWrite(AfterWriteEventArgs<User> e)
    {
        e.RecordLine = e.RecordLine.Trim(',');
    }
}
```